# Validar Campo com javaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Preciso validar alguns campo, obrigando o usuário a fornecer os dados antes de salvar em banco, se ele não fornecer os dados, a borda do controle fica vermelha informando que tem alguma coisa de erra com o campo.

Eu já consegui validar por javascript no evento onBlur para o campo ficar vermelho, mais quando eu salvo o botão salvar do um poste na pagina  e os campo que estava com a borda vermelha perde a cor.

Tem como a cada poste da página chamar o javascript, para validar os campos?

o código em javascript

```
function ValidatxtECFNrSerie(controle) {

                if (controle == '') {
                    $('#' + '<%= txtECFNrSerie.ClientID %>').addClass('validationError'); 
                }
                else {
                    $('#' + '<%= txtECFNrSerie.ClientID %>').removeClass('validationError');
                }

        }`

     <asp:Label ID="lblNrSerieECF" Text="Nr. Série ECF/SAT:" runat="server" />
           </div>
                <div class="dataForm">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtECFNrSerie" runat="server" MaxLength="15" Width="150px" onBlur="javascript:ValidatxtECFNrSerie(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>
           </div>
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar o http://jqueryvalidation.org/ Jquery Validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu gerei uma extensão em jQuery, seja se ajuda.

- Note que tanto no **blur** como no **submit** ele valida os campos

```js
var validForm = false;

(function (jQuery){
 jQuery.fn.validate = function(callbackCheck, callbackError){
 
  var focus = false;
  var pass = true;

  var classError = 'error-input';

  jQuery(this).each(function(){
   var value = jQuery(this).val();
   if(value == '' || (typeof(callbackCheck) == 'function' && callbackCheck(this))){
    jQuery(this).addClass(classError);
    pass = false;
    
    if(!focus){
     jQuery(this).focus();
     focus = true;
    }

    if(typeof(callbackError) == 'function'){
     callbackError(this);
    }
   }else{
    jQuery(this).removeClass(classError);
   }
  });
  
  validForm = pass;
  
  return this;
 };
})(jQuery);

function formValidate(_this){
 jQuery(_this).find('input[type!="submit"],select').validate();
}

function inputValidate(_this){
 jQuery(_this).validate(); 
}
```

```css
.error-input{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onSubmit="formValidate(this)" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
  <input type="texte" onBlur="inputValidate(this)"/>
  <input type="texte" onBlur="inputValidate(this)"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um jeito sujo de fazer isso:

```
<% if(Request.IsPostBack){ %>
jQuery(function() {
      ['<%= txtECFNrSerie.ClientID %>', '<%= Outro1.ClientID %>', '<%= OutroEAssimPorDiante.ClientID %>'].forEach(function(id) {
          ValidatxtECFNrSerie($(id).val();
          });
      });
<% } %>
```